# So easy inequality in complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that $$|z| \lt 1 \Rightarrow |z-i| \lt \sqrt 2$$
$x^2+y^2 \lt 1$
How can I show $x^2+(y-1)^2 \lt 2$ ?
I’m sorry, i know it’s so easy but I couldnt obtain it in no way.

Comment: Not true at all, this "so easy inequality", that's why you are struggling.

Comment: You have probably a typo. Instead of $\sqrt 2$ put $2$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг could you please glance my comment below?

Answer (score 4):

This is incorrect. Consider $z=-\frac{1}{2}i$. Then $|z|=\frac{1}{2}<1$ but $|z-i|=\left|-\frac{1}{2}i-i\right|=\left|-\frac{3}{2}i\right|=\frac{3}{2}>\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: OK. Thanks. How can I show |z-i|<sqrt2 when finding taylor expansion around i of 1/z via using Maclaurin expansion of 1/z?

Comment: @user519955 You cannot show $|z-i| < \sqrt 2$ because it is not true, right? Please clarify your context further, maybe we can infer the right question from this.

Answer (score 0):

After the correction $\sqrt 2\to 2$: use the triangle inequality:
$$|z - i|\le |z| + |i|< 1 + 1 = 2.$$